# Android: Difference Between Large and Xlarge Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have an app that I am creating. I want to have this app support tablets, so I created a folder in my res: `res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml`. However, when I run my app on a tablet (defined as 7" or above) the layouts are not used from the `layout-xlarge` folder, but instead from the `layout` folder.

I then discovered that there were also `layout-large` layouts that I could use too. I haven't yet tried them, but I will.

I would like to know what is the difference between `layout` files, `layout-large` files and `layout-xlarge` files. Which one would be the best to use for tablet layouts?

Thanks!

Comment: hi use the folder like layout/xlarge-hdpi, layout/xlarge-xhdpi something like this. for mobile it is layout/normal-hdpi, layout/normal-xhdpi,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Android documentation - Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
>
> large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
>
> normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
>
> small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Which one to use, as you can see, depends on the dimensions of the device you're aiming for. You probably want to build your app so it will support as much devices as possible.

Comment: So what your saying is that theoretically a tablet could use a small Layout and a phone could use an xlarge Layout depending on the dp of that device?

Comment: No, I don't say that :)

Btw, you might want to condier using sw qualifier instead, e.g.:
7" tablets: Instead of layout-large, use layout-sw600dp.
10" tablets: Instead of layout-xlarge, use layout-sw720dp.

Comment: layout-sw600dp is always for 7" tablets and up and layout-sw720dp is always for 10" tablets and above?

Comment: This is the general guidline.
If you need to check specific devices you might want to use this site:
http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php

Comment: Okay. I will have to try this out a bit later, but if it works, I should accept it within 24 hours. Thanks :)

Comment: No problm. I'll be waiting anxiously in the next 24 hours ;)

Comment: Thanks again for your help

Comment: Note: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups (large, large, etc) are deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based on the available screen width. If you're developing for Android 3.2 and greater, see Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2 for more information. ref: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

Answer (score 1):

In Android we need to maintain different folders for the layouts with different resolution reason behind it is the use or the resolution of the Android Device on which the application gonna execute.

**small Resources for small size screens.**

**normal Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)**

**large Resources for large size screens.**

**xlarge Resources for extra large size screens.**

Android OS select the specific layout it self by checking the compatible device and its resolution.

So, better to create folders to support in multiple screens

Comment: Note: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups (large, large, etc) are deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based on the available screen width. If you're developing for Android 3.2 and greater, see Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2 for more information. ref: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)